# How can I get the feature importance of a CatBoost in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost, catboost

So I was running a Catboost model using Python, which was pretty simple, basically:

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool, cv
catboost_model = CatBoostClassifier(
    cat_features=["categorical_variable_1", "categorical_variable_2"],
    loss_function="Logloss",
    eval_metric="AUC",
    iterations=200,
)
```

So I wanted to get the feature importance. With XGBoost Classifier, I could prepare a dataframe with the feature importance doing something like:

```
importances = xgb_model.get_fscore()

feat_list = []
date = datetime.today()
for feature, importance in importances.items():
    dummy_list.append([date, feature, importance])

feat_df = pd.DataFrame(feat_list, columns=['date', 'feature', 'importance'])
```

Now, I wanted to do the same thing with CatBoost features. I started by doing:

```
catboost_model.get_feature_importance(
Pool(X_train, y_train, cat_features=["categorical_variable_1", "categorical_variable_2"]))
```

But I don't know how to move on from this (which should be very simple, but I'm lost). Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Can you post the output you get from the last line of code `catboost_model.get_feature_importance()`

Comment: It's just an array, like this: array([0.4, 0.2, ..., 0.5])

Answer (score 8):

In short, you can do something like

```
pd.DataFrame({'feature_importance': model.get_feature_importance(train_pool), 
              'feature_names': x_val.columns}).sort_values(by=['feature_importance'], 
                                                           ascending=False)
```

you can also make a function like (I found the explanation on Analyseup.com [here](https://www.analyseup.com/learn-python-for-data-science/python-random-forest-feature-importance-plot.html)

```
def plot_feature_importance(importance,names,model_type):
    
    #Create arrays from feature importance and feature names
    feature_importance = np.array(importance)
    feature_names = np.array(names)
    
    #Create a DataFrame using a Dictionary
    data={'feature_names':feature_names,'feature_importance':feature_importance}
    fi_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    #Sort the DataFrame in order decreasing feature importance
    fi_df.sort_values(by=['feature_importance'], ascending=False,inplace=True))
    
    #Define size of bar plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    #Plot Searborn bar chart
    sns.barplot(x=fi_df['feature_importance'], y=fi_df['feature_names'])
    #Add chart labels
    plt.title(model_type + 'FEATURE IMPORTANCE')
    plt.xlabel('FEATURE IMPORTANCE')
    plt.ylabel('FEATURE NAMES')
```

and plot the feature importance from different boosting algorithm

```
#plot the xgboost result
plot_feature_importance(xgb_model.feature_importances_,train.columns,'XG BOOST')

#plot the catboost result
plot_feature_importance(cb_model.get_feature_importance(),train.columns,'CATBOOST')
```

Comment: This generates thounds of plots for me. Does this create feature importance plots for every tree which was fitted?

Answer (score 7):

Now you already have a Dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'feature_importance': model.get_feature_importance(train_pool), 
              'feature_names': x_val.columns}).sort_values(by=['feature_importance'], 
                                                       ascending=False)
```

I found it easier to plot using the inbuilt pandas tool, for instance for the top 20 features:

```
data[:20].sort_values(by=['feature_importance'], ascending=True).plot.barh(x='feature_names', y='feature_importance')
```